# How does a web server/container treat a POJO in respect to other classes like EJB's and Entities?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, stateless-session-bean

I'm trying to use plain old java objects(POJO)'s and regular class files where needed and only use EJBs when I need the functionality that they add such as asynchronous calls, pooling, etc.  I'm wondering how the server treats this behavior once the project is deployed on a server. Since it is not managed by the container does a new instance have to be created for every stateless session bean pooled that might call one of it's methods? How do things like static methods or state affect this model.

Edit:

1) I can clarify more.  The point of Java EE is that you annotate a POJO with @stateless etc so that a container can manage it. You don't have to declare a new instance of a stateless bean you just inject and can make calls to it's type.

2) Most Java EE tutorials and books never mention non annotated classes as a part of your business logic. It's never brought up. This seems strange to me if you can use them in Java EE projects for your business logic and it can get deployed on a server.  If you don't need pooling or asynchronous access--the things that a container helps manager through an EJB then you can use theses regular POJO's in your Java EE project.

3) that leads me to my question which is how do I incorporate properly into a project? Do I put them in the EJB project that's connected to an EAR or should they go in the EAR? or Dynamic web project.  There is almost no mention or instruction on proper use of regular objects like this. When it gets compiled into a WAR for deployment are there any issues you run into on the server? Isn't it expecting properly annotated EJBs, servlets or JSP?

Comment: you're going to need to provide more details.  your question is very vague and confusing.

Comment: It's vague question because I'm expecting a vague answer. I'm looking for proper use of regular java objects that aren't annotated and therefore managed by the java server container. This is important to me because I have a project that I don't think the class needs to be an EJB but in all my books and what I've read online they never address non EJB business logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The don't affect it at all. Classes are classes, objects are objects. They're no managed, they're not interfered with, nothing happens to them. They're not special is any way.

Static singletons are static singletons, Java is java.

All you need to be aware of is the classloader layout of your container, and how it relates to your deployed applications and resources. (Classes in one app can't see classes in another app, for example.) Most of the time it's not really important. Sometimes, it is, as things get more complicated.

But for the most part, it's just Java.

Addenda:

A better way to look at this is to simply group your classes up in to blocks of locality.

Let's take a simple web app that uses EJBs.

The web app is deployed in a WAR artifact, and the EJBs can be deployed separately, as individual EJBs in the container, or, more likely, in an EAR. When you package your application in an EAR, you will likely bundle the WAR within the EAR as well. So, in the end the EAR contains your WAR, and your EJBs.

Now during development, in this case, you're going to have classes that have are in one of three categories.

1. Classes that are relevant solely to the EJBs (for example the Session Beans).
2. Classes that are relevant solely to the WARs (such as a Servlet class).
3. Classes that are relevant to both (a database entity perhaps).

So, a simple way to package them is in three jar files. A jar file for your WAR (in fact, this is the WAR, with the classes in WEB-INF/classes), a jar file for your EJBs, and a jar file for the 3rd type, we'll call that a library.

In terms of build dependency, the WAR build depends on the lib, and the EJB build depends on the lib. But neither the WAR nor EJB depend on each other, as they don't share anything directly, only indirectly through the 3rd library jar. The lib jar is stand alone, since it doesn't have any dependency on either the WAR or EJBs. Note, your EJB Session Bean interface classes will go in to the library jar (since both tiers rely upon them).

In your ear, you simply bundle the lib jar, the WAR, and the EJB jar along with a META-INF dir and an application.xml file. The WAR has its own structure, with the WEB-INF and all, the EJB jar has its META-INF and ejb-jar.xml. But of note is the that lib.jar is NOT in the WEB-INF/lib directory, it's in the EAR bundle and thus shared by both the EJBs and the WAR using class loader chicanery that the container is responsible for.

This is important to note. For example, if you have, say, a simple static Singleton in your lib jar, then BOTH the WAR and EJBs will share that Singleton, since they're all part of the same class loader. To use that Singleton, it's just normal Java. Nothing special there.

If the EJB and WAR were deployed separately, they would EACH need there own copy of the lib.jar, and in the case of the Singleton, they would NOT share it, since each module would have it's own class loader.

So, barring some real burning need otherwise, it's easier to bundle everything in to an EAR and treat both the EJB tier and WAR tier as a single, integrated application.

Addenda 2:

People don't much talk about using classes in Java EE development because there's nothing to talk about, they just use them, like in any Java program. You're over thinking this here.

The 3 jar idiom: war, ejb, lib is one I've used over the years because it separates the 3 concerns, and limits dependencies. Client -> lib -> EJB. It also simplifies the build, since clients typically need just the lib jar and java. In the Netbeans IDE, this is trivial to manage. With minor work, it's straightforward in other IDEs or even in ant/maven. It's not a huge burden, but keeps the 3 parts relatively clean.

Dependency and Jar management is the nightmare of any large Java project, and even more so with EJB when you're dealing with the different deployable artifacts. Anything that can help mitigate that is a win, in my book, and truth is, a clean, stand alone lib jar helps a lot, especially of you need to integrate and use that lib with other code. For example, if you later write an external GUI client using Remote EJBs, or even web services, the lib jar is the only dependency that client has. The benefits of this jar far outweigh the minor pain it takes to set up this kind of library.

In the end the lib jar is just a jar like any other jar you'd want to use in your application (like logging or any other popular 3rd party jars).

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm just confusing myself because I'm being trained in a school of "EJB's are for business logic" and no mention of the fact that you can easily use regular java classes without annotation for logic. So that clears it up. I don't know why my question was down voted I'm just trying to understand JEE better. I'll accept this as the answer as soon as people have had a chance to consider my new comments. Thanks

Comment: So what you're saying is that the reason most people don't mention normal java classes as part of JEE web development is because they're more work than simply using EJB's? Since you have to include them in separate jar library files whereas EJBs are just bundled with the normal war/ear deployment?

Comment: Couldn't I just put them int he EJB project and then they would get deployed normally?